# How do I create a bitmap image as spritefont with multiple character regions?

Tags: xna, spritefont

How do I create a bitmap font image that contains characters from multiple regions and is correctly interpreted by XNA content pipeline?

I want to add some special characters to my bitmap font image, but I don't know how to do it correctly.

**UPD:** I think I'm getting closer to my answer. Sprite font texture content processor looks for non-magenta squares in the image and probably uses an xml settings file like with normal spritefonts to map each square to a corresponding symbol. I should probably edit that xml file for my custom texture, but I don't know where I can find it yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no XML file.

**You have to create a custom content processor. Inherit that processor from `FontTextureProcessor` and override the `GetCharacterForIndex` method.**

Have your method return the character for the specified index in your texture.

The default implementation simply returns `FirstCharacter + index`. Yours can use whatever logic it likes. (I guess you could even make it parse an XML file for the data.)

(Note that, for a single region, you can specify what `FirstCharacter` is in the properties for the "Sprite Font Texture" content processor, in the properties window (F4) for that content file.)

Comment: Seems a little bit strange nobody's asked these questions before.